# Como puedo capturar una excepción y repetir la línea que me esta solicitando el dato de tipo entero, ya que en mi código se vuelve un bucle infinito

Tags: java, excepciones, while

¿Como puedo salir del bucle infinito, siguiendo capturar la excepción en caso de ingresos inválidos?

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
         //instancia a scanner
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        //entero en el que se almacenara la edad
        int edad;

        //condicional para repetir la solicitud de edad
        while(true){
            System.out.println("introduce edad");
        /*try catch para almacenar una excepcion en caso de que se introdusca una cadena*/
            try {
                edad = entrada.nextInt();
            } catch(InputMismatchException e){
                entrada.next();
                System.out.println( "error");
            }// cierre del try catch
        }//cierre del while
    }
}
```

Comment: while (true) va a ser infinito aunque no entre por el catch. por favor expande la idea de lo que quisiste hacer o a que quieres llegar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

he tomado tu codigo y lo modifique , te comente las cosas que agregue y debe quedar asi :

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    //instancia a scanner
   Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
   //entero en el que se almacenara la edad
   int edad;

   boolean repetir = true;//bandera para indicar cuando el bucle debe terminar ,caso de ingreso de edad exitoso
   //condicional para repetir la solicitud de edad
   while(repetir){
       System.out.println("introduce edad");
   /*try catch para almacenar una excepcion en caso de que se introdusca una cadena*/
       try {
           edad = entrada.nextInt();
           repetir = false;//cambiamos el valor de la bandera a false para que no se vuelva a repetir ya que no se produjo una exception, recibiendo solo numeros
       } catch(InputMismatchException e){
           entrada.nextLine();
           System.out.println( "error");
       }// cierre del try catch
   }//cierre del while
}//cierra metodo main
```

Answer (score 4):

Para hacer validaciones es mejor usar do-while, de una forma similar a esta:

```
int edad = -1;
do {
    System.out.println("introduce edad");
    try {
        edad = entrada.nextInt();
    } catch(InputMismatchException e){
        System.out.println( "error");
    }
} while (edad > 0 && edad < 99);
```

entonces si `nextInt` devuelve un valor numérico y no una excepción, validas el valor dentro del rango que quieres, si la excepción es lanzada, `edad` vale -1 y vuelve a ejecutarse el ciclo hasta que se ingrese un valor dentro del rango.

Comment: no la había intentado con  el do while gracias

Comment: Recomiendo agregar `entrada.nextLine()` luego de leer el valor de `nextInt`.

Comment: @EduardoFarias, si la respuesta ha solucionado tu problema, por favor, [acepta la respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Usando [`break`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
         //instancia a scanner
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        //entero en el que se almacenara la edad
        int edad;

        //condicional para repetir la solicitud de edad
        while(true){
            System.out.println("introduce edad");
        /*try catch para almacenar una excepcion en caso de que se introdusca una cadena*/
            try {
                edad = entrada.nextInt();
                break; // si tenemos un int, tenemos edad
            } catch(InputMismatchException e){
                entrada.next();
                System.out.println( "error");
            }// cierre del try catch
        }//cierre del while, break te lleva aquí
        System.out.println(String.format("Edad: %d", edad));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Con un simple Do While puedes sacarlo, y controlando cuando sales del bucle:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

//instanciamos un objeto de scanner
Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

//entero en el que se almacenara la edad
int edad;

//Usamos una variable booleana para indicar cuando el bucle debe terminar ,en el caso de ingresar el dato correctamente
boolean repetir = true;

//Utilizamos un bucle do while, que en este caso es mas eficiente que el while
do{
   System.out.println("Introduce la Edad: ");
/*try catch para almacenar una excepcion en caso de que se introdusca una cadena*/
   try {
       edad = entrada.nextInt();
       repetir = false;//cambiamos el valor de la bandera a false para que no se vuelva a repetir ya que no se produjo una exception, recibiendo solo numeros
   } catch(InputMismatchException e){
       entrada.nextLine();
       System.out.println("Error, has introducido mal la edad");
   }// cierre del try catch
}while(repetir);//cierre del do

}//Cierre del main
```